# range splitting problem

Tags: algorithm, range, split, overlapping

folks,

have heard of this problem quite some time back. thought of posting it, to get some views of doing this like using some construct or other efficient means(specialized trees may be)

> Given a set of ranges in pairs (5,18) (12,23) (15,30)
>
> split them into all possible subranges which are seen overlapping other ranges in the set.
> like  (5,11) (12,14) (15,18) (19,23) (24,30)

thanks all, appreciate that...

rajan...

PS is this aa standard problem, if yes, would like tu know its name

Comment: Could you clarify your example a bit? Is (5,11),(12,14),(15,18),(19,23),(24,30) a complete answer to the input (5,18),(12,23),(15,30)?

Comment: yes aioobe... its the complete solution

Answer (score 5):

Chuck all range endpoints into a list, but mark them as start/end-points.

```
[(5, S), (18, E), (12, S), (23, E), (15, S), (30, E)]
```

Sort them by position, breaking ties by putting start-points before end-points.

```
[(5, S), (12, S), (15, S), (18, E), (23, E), (30, E)]
```

Then you can work out the ranges by iterating through this list, keeping track of how many start- minus end-points we've processed so far. If we see a start point, that's a start of a new range to output. If our count is positive, we have to end to current range first though. If we see an end point, end the current range.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after quite some tinkering I was able to implement an apparently working version. So for those that are looking for a working solution, here is mine:

```
private static class RangeVal implements Comparable<RangeVal> {
    public final BigInteger value;
    public int count;

    public RangeVal(BigInteger value, int count) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value + (isStart() ? "S" : "E") + count;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(RangeVal o) {
        // Sort by value first
        int v = value.compareTo(o.value);
        if (v != 0)
            return v;
        // Then sort Starts before ends
        return -count;
    }

    public boolean isStart() {
        return count > 0;
    }

}

/**
 * Sort a List of ranges by their number, then start/end and merge multiple
 * start/ends
 * 
 * @param temp
 *            a list of RangeVal which can be unsorted
 */
private static void preSort(List<RangeVal> temp) {
    Collections.sort(temp);
    RangeVal last = null;
    for (Iterator<RangeVal> iterator = temp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        RangeVal rangeVal = iterator.next();
        if ((last != null) && last.value.equals(rangeVal.value) && (last.isStart() == rangeVal.isStart())) {
            iterator.remove();
            last.count += rangeVal.count;
        } else
            last = rangeVal;
    }
}

/**
 * Splits a list into ValueRange Objects that do not overlap each other, but
 * fully represent the ranges given by value
 * 
 * @param value
 *            a list of RangeVal Objects that need to be split
 * @return
 */
private static SortedSet<ValueRange> split(List<RangeVal> value) {
    preSort(value);
    SortedSet<ValueRange> res = new TreeSet<ValueRange>();
    int count = 0;
    BigInteger start = null;
    for (RangeVal rangeVal : value) {
        count += rangeVal.count;
        if (rangeVal.isStart()) {
            if (start != null) {
                //If there was an unended start, then we have to end it just one before the new start
                res.add(new ValueRange(start, rangeVal.value.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
            }
            //Set the start to the current Element
            start = rangeVal.value;
        } else {
            //End the current range at this Element
            res.add(new ValueRange(start, rangeVal.value));
            if (count > 0) {
                //If we expect another end later, the element following this will have to start one after
                start = rangeVal.value.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            } else
                //No new range anymore
                start = null;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // 5->8 9->10 11
    System.out.println(split(createRanges(5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11)));
    // 5, 6->7, 8, 9, 10
    System.out.println(split(createRanges(5, 10, 6, 8, 8, 9)));
    System.out.println(split(createRanges(5, 10, 6, 8, 8, 9, 6, 9)));
    System.out.println(split(createRanges(5, 10, 6, 8, 8, 9, 6, 9, 6, 11, 8, 9)));
    System.out.println(split(createRanges(5, 10, 6, 8, 8, 9, 6, 9, 6, 11, 8, 9, 14, 18)));
}

private static List<RangeVal> createRanges(int... r) {
    List<RangeVal> temp = new LinkedList<RangeVal>();
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        temp.add(new RangeVal(BigInteger.valueOf(r[i]), (i % 2) == 0 ? 1 : -1));
    }
    System.out.println("HDLSimulator.createRanges()" + temp);
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something, but this seems like a simple solution:
Throw all the numbers in a C++ STL set container. They will be automatically ordered in the ascending order. so they will read out in this fashion:
5,12,15,18,23,30
So if you can tolerate overlap then:
(5,12) (12,15) (15,18), (18,23) (23,30) are the ranges that are constructed by repeating every number twice expect the first and the last and then grouping two numbers.

If you cannot tolerate overlap, the ranges can be constructed by putting an incremented number in the list instead of repeating it.